# Getting all top level parents in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, codeigniter, hierarchical-data

I have a table storing parent and child relationship like below:

| ParentID | ChildID |
| --- | --- |
| 1727731 | 1727733 |
| 1727732 | 1727733 |
| 1727733 | 1727734 |
| 1727733 | 1727735 |
| 1727770 | 1727771 |
| 1727771 | 1727772 |

Below codes are how I get to the top level parent.

```
function getTopLevelParent($id) {

    while ($result = $this->_processGetTopLevelParent($id)) {
        if (count($result) == 1) {
            $id = $result[0]['ParentID'];

            // I can easily get to the top level parent if the child has only one parent
            // eg. for $id = 1727772, I can get its top parent 1727770
        }
        else if (count($result) > 1) {
            // What shall I do?
        }
    }
    return $id; // Will be modified accordingly as I may need to return an array of parents
}
    
private function _processGetTopLevelParent($id) {
        $sql = "SELECT ParentID FROM Family WHERE ChildID = " . (int)$id . " ORDER BY ParentID ASC";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $query->result_array();

        // fyi, the array return is formatted like below example:
        // array( '0' => array('ParentID' => 1722731), '1' => array('ParentID' => 1722732))
}
```

However, we see that `1727733` is the parent for two children (`1727734`, `1727735`) and also a child of two parents (`1727731`, `1727732`).

In reality, I wouldn't know that `1727731` and `1727732` are top level parents. So I have to check each one using similar methods. But I'm stuck on what to do within the `else-if` statement in the `getTopLevelParent` function. I'm thinking of something like below:

```
    foreach ($result as $r) {
        while ($newResult = $this->_processGetTopLevelParent($r['ParentID'])) {
                // basically repeating like the outer while loop
        }
    }
```

But I also thought that this could be an endless repetition because `1727731` and `1727732` may also be the child with more than one parent, same goes to their parents' parent...

Any idea what can be done?

Thank you!

Comment: If you just want the base parent records, couldn't you just check where there is no record with a particular ID as the child ID?

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks for your suggestion. But my concern is, if the input $id is a child, for example `1727735`, then I still need to trace back to its parent, its parent's parents and so on...to get the base parent(s). So then only I can do as what you have suggested, ain't it?

Comment: You need to make your function take an array of arguments and return an array of results (since you can have multiple parents) and then call it recursively until you reach the top level for all of the potential branches of the family tree.